# Google Cloud Sql Proxy error while executing the file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-sql-proxy

This is the command I run in my shell: `./cloud_sql_proxy -instaces=[my_project_id:europe-west3:my_project_name]=tcp=5432`.

Sometimes i got the following errors messages:

- **CASE 1**: `flag provided but not defined: -instaces`;
- **CASE 2**: `2021/11/19 17:50:12 errors parsing config:`

  ```
   mkdir my_project_id:europe-west3:my_project_name: The syntax of the file, directory, or volume name is incorrect.
   mkdir my_project_id:europe-west3:my_project_name-copy: The syntax of the file, directory, or volume name is incorrect.
  ```

Comment: You have typo. You should run `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my_project_id:europe-west3:my_project_name=tcp:5432`

Comment: thank you. I am still studying how Google Cloud works, if you post your comment I will accept the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by running `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my_project_id:europe-west3:my_project_name=tcp:5432` in my shell.

Comment: Can you explain what is this =tcp:5432 weird syntax?

Comment: I honestly cannot, because I asked myself the same question. I don't remember how I did find this solution, but I remember it looked like some formatting error. I believe the "=" character, mixed up with the "[]" characters caused the error. DId you solve this?